# how to use prototype in typescript

Tags: typescript

first i use fill function

```
const range = new Array(layernum.length).fill(NaN);//[ts] Property 'fill' does not exist on type 'any[]'
```

to deal with this problem,i use

```
const range = new Int32Array(layernum.length).fill(NaN);
```

instead

while,it cause another problem

```
let layer = range.map(e => range.map(e => e)); //Type 'Int32Array' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

so how to use prototype in Typescript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fill` method of array exists only in ES6 or above. In order for typescript to recognize the propper ES6 version of the Array class you need to make sure you include `es6` in the `lib` property of your `tsconfig.json`. For example:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib" : ["es6", "dom"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want/can't use the `lib.es6.d.ts`, then you can update the compiler with the [method signature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4191):

```
declare global {
    interface Array<T> {
        fill(value: T, start?: number, end?: number): this;
    }
}
```